# Using a slot-scope to show text, doesn't show ñ character?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, utf-8

I'm using a slot-scope to show text where there could be special characters like ñ or letters with accents, how to make sure those show up the right way?

This is the outcome right now

```
Opiniones acerca de las decoraciones navide\u00f1as en las oficinas centrales. tiene un comentario eliminado.
```

This is the expected outcome

```
Opiniones acerca de las decoraciones navideñas en las oficinas centrales. tiene un comentario eliminado.
```

I'm setting the info like this in the controller, 
to call the info for the table I call `Activity::all()`

```
activity()
    ->performedOn($comment)
    ->withProperty('user', auth()->user()->name)
    ->log($comment->discussionForum()->pluck('theme') . ' tiene un comentario eliminado.');
```

I'm showing the text like this in a table

```
<el-table-column>
    <template slot-scope="scope">
        {{ scope.row.description }}
    </template>
</el-table-column>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I came up with, using the foreign keys to call the model and find the name that way. Since I'm adding this activity when the person saves a comment I can use the FK

```
$theme = DiscussionForum::where('id', $request->forum_id)->pluck('theme')->first();

activity()
    ->performedOn($comment)
    ->withProperty('user', auth()->user()->name)
    ->log($theme . ' tiene un nuevo comentario.');
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the character encoding in your HTML template so that it can read these letters correctly, e.g.
`<meta charset="UTF-8">`. Without the charset set, some characters do not appear how they should.

If you have no luck with this, I would try adding the encoding to AppServiceProvider.php in the `boot` function:

`\Blade::setEchoFormat('e(utf8_encode(%s))');`

Comment: The issue is when I'm retrieving the data here `$comment->discussionForum()->pluck('theme')`, when I set it without calling relationships for other activity it brings the special characters but not when it's called the above way

Comment: @Nancy that seems strange... to clarify, have you set the charset? Are these characters showing up fine in the database or do they appear incorrectly encoded there too?

Comment: They show up as expected in the database, but when I bring it with the relationship and I do a `Log::info` it shows up without those special character.

Comment: You might have to change it elsewhere also, I've added a new thing to try @Nancy :)

Comment: Where should I put that, I'm not really using blade, I'm using Inertia and vue.js for my views

Comment: @Nancy it's a Laravel file:  app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php